# Python reset to 0 a Multidimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to code a function which resets the values of a multidimensional array. The multidimensional array can have any depth and the arrays can have any length. We can think about those array as trees where i need to set to 0 all the  leafs.

The code should look like this.

```
 @staticmethod
 def reset_to_0(the_array):
     ....................
     ....................
     #There is no return. The parameter 'the_array' is passed by reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop to iterate the elements in the array, and recursion to descent into deeper levels.

```
def reset_to_0(the_array):
    for i, e in enumerate(the_array):
        if isinstance(e, list):
            reset_to_0(e)
        else:
            the_array[i] = 0
```

Example:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], 4, 5, [6, [7, 8, [9]]]]
>>> reset_to_0(a)
print a
[[0, 0, 0], 0, 0, [0, [0, 0, [0]]]]
```

Comment: Perfect just what i needed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using numpy arrays then `the_array[...] = 0` should do the trick.

Comment: No I am not using numpy arrays, and i'd like not to use